# CORS call working in PHP, but not in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a CORS call to a server and I tried using javascript/jquery with no luck, but PHP is working fine. What can I do to make this work ?

**My PHP code (WORKING):**

```
function getQueries(){
    $curl = curl_init();

    $url = "http://some-domain/search/";

    // Optional Authentication:

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Language: en-US'));

    $output =  curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return json_decode($output);
}
```

**My javascript code (NOT WORKING):**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://some-domain/search/",
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    beforeSend: setHeader,
    success: makeDiv()
});

function setHeader(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'en-US');
}
```

dealing with PHP code sending data to javascript and scheduling and other things have become a pain and want to get rid of php and make everything work via Javascript/Jquery.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: If possible, can post url ? Thanks

Comment: in PHP there are no Same Origin Policy restrictions as far as I know(not a PHP guy)... It is a browser feature... so in order to make the ajax call work in the client side the target resource has to support CORS(need to add the CORS headers to response)

Comment: If the target source is not supporting CORS then you can make your PHP server act like a proxy server which will delegate the requests to the target source and then forward the response to the client

Comment: PHP proxy looks like a good idea. will try that.

@guest271314: unfortunately I can't post URL. work related. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS is used to share resources across multiple domains in web browser(to avoid Same Origin Policy violations).

Since the http client implementations in PHP is not restricted by the Same Origin Policy restrictions CORS will not have any effect in it.

But if you are trying to access a external domain using ajax and it is not supporting CORS then the browser will throw Same Origin Policy violation error.

To overcome this either the target resource has to add support for CORS or you can make your web server act like a proxy which will receive requests from the browser and forward the request to the target resource then receive the response and forward the response to the client.